# Fourier transform of the amplitude of a laser evolving along $x$-axis: how the cross-section appear?

Tags: electromagnetism, fourier-transform

Consider the vector potential describing the field of a laser defined for $x>0$. It has a cross-section $L^2$. The field propagates along the $x$-axis.

In the book "Quantum measurement theory and its application", on page 459, they write the following formulas :

$$A(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi L^2/2}} \int_0^{+ \infty} A(k,t)cos(kx) dk$$
$$A(k,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi /(2L^2)}} \int_0^{+ \infty} A(x,t)cos(kx) dx$$

(they use the fourier transform on the cos basis as we can prolongate on $x<0$ the function by the symmetric one, thus only the cos will appear) :

**My question :** They say that the $L^2$ term come from the cross-section. But I don't understand this formula. How does this $L^2$ appear ?

---

**My try to understand it :**

If I have a $L$-periodic $1D$ function, I have :

$$\widehat{f}(k)=\frac{1}{L} \int_{-L/2}^{L/2}f(x)e^{ikx}dx$$
Where $k=\frac{2 \pi}{L} n$.

And :

$$f(x)=\sum_k \widehat{f}(k) e^{i kx}$$

For a constant function over $L$, I can apply boundary conditions and thus I will only have the $0$ frequency that wont vanish : $\widehat{f}(k)=\delta_{k,0} f(0)$

If I apply this to my problem, I use periodic boundary conditions on $y$ and $z$, and I should have in the end :

$$ \widehat{A}(k_x,k_y,k_z,t)=\delta_{(k_y,0)} \delta_{(k_z,0)}\int_{- \infty}^{+\infty} A(x,0,0) e^{i k_x x} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} $$

Using the symmetry of the function, I end up with :

$$ \widehat{A}(k_x,k_y,k_z,t)=\delta_{(k_y,0)} \delta_{(k_z,0)}\int_{0}^{+\infty} A(x,0,0) 2 cos(k_x x) \frac{dx}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} $$

Which, using the same notations as in the book, would mean :

$$ \widehat{A}(k,t)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{0}^{+\infty} A(x,t) cos(k_x x) dx $$

As you can see the formula is different....

Where is my mistake / how do they obtain the formulas they give ?

Comment: Isn't the above integral equivalent to $\widehat{A}(k,t)=\frac{1}{\pi^2} \int_{0}^{+\infty} A(x,t) cos(k_x x) dx$? And if I'm reading this correctly, isn't $\delta_{(k_y,0)} \delta_{(k_z,0)}$ always equal to $0$ since there is no $k_{y}$ , or $k_{z}$? In any case, I would guess the cross sectional area of the laser beam is $L^2\pi$ where $L$ is the waist of beam.

Comment: @CinaedSimson I had an extra 1/sqrt(2pi) in my last line. I removed it. For the delta, they are 0 if ky,kz !=0, and 1 if kx=ky=0. Because of the periodic boundary conditions I applied, I will have the 0 frequency along axis y and z only. This is what is assumed in my last line (I assume I am at ky=kz=0).

Comment: check the dimensions first. The first integral is over $k$ with dimension of $1/L$ and the second integral is over $x$ with dimension of $L$. So there will be some constant to make sure the final result is dimensionless.

Comment: @IamAStudent if you remove L from the formulas given in the book, the result is still dimension consistant. You will have $A(x,t)$ that has the dimension of $A(k,t)$ divided by a distance (because of $dk$), and $A(k,t)$ that has the dimension of $A(x,t)$ times a distance (becaue of $dx$). So the result, without the L (as I did in my calculation) is still consistant with respect to dimensions.